# Computed column - trigger instead of insert

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a computed column in a table (MyTable). I also have a trigger on it.
The trigegr does something like

```
INSERT INTO MyTable
SELECT * FROM inserted
```

and there's the problem: the 'inserted' table has the computed column in it, so the column definitions don't match, cause you cannot insert values into computed column.

Is there some automatic solution for this or I must declare all columns by name - I'd rather not do it because I would have to change the trigger every time I change the table.

Comment: outside of `EXISTS` checks, `SELECT *` is just a lazy habit that you should get out of. You should *know* what columns you're interested in, and you shouldn't force the system to do *more* work just because you want to cut down on typing. Some tools do assist you with populating such lists (e.g. if you have a table visibile in SSMS's object explorer, and you drag the `Columns` folder into a query window, that will be automatically expanded out into all of the column names)

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to list the columns by name, or use dynamic sql, which I would advise against.

It's not a good practice using SELECT * in production code anyway.